# Implementation of the Radau IIA 5th order method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

How to get the RadauIIA 5th order in terms of its K(i), just like the RK4 Classic?

\begin{align}
k_1 &= f(t_{n},y_{n})
\\
k_2 &= f(t_{n}+ \frac{h}{2},y_{n}+h\frac{k_1}{2})
\\
k_3 &= f(t_{n}+ \frac{h}{2},y_{n}+h\frac{k_2}{2})
\\
k_4 &= f(t_{n}+ h,y_{n}+hk_3)
\\\hline
y_{n+1} &= y_{n} + \frac{1}{6}h(k_1+2k_2+2k_3+k_4)
\end{align}
Or for example the implicit Trapezium is given by the following formula:

$$
y_{n+1} = y_{n} + \frac{1}{2}h(f(t_{n},y_{n}) + f(t_{n+1},y_{n+1}))
$$

Is the Radau IIA 5th order as such:

\begin{align}
k_1 &= h * f(t_{n} + c1 * h, y_{n} + (a11*k1 + a12*k2 + a13*k3))
\\
k_2 &= h * f(t_{n} + c2 * h, y_{n} + (a21*k1 + a22*k2 + a23*k3))
\\
k_3 &= h * f(t_{n} + c3 * h, y_{n} + (a31*k1 + a32*k2 + a33*k3))
\\\hline
y_{n+1} &= y_{n} + (b1*k1 + b2*k2 + b3*k3)
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

The Butcher tableau for Radau IIA as per Hairer-Wanner: *"Solving ODE II: Stiff & DAE"*, 2nd ed., page 74 is

\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\frac{4-\sqrt{6}}{10}&\frac{88-7\sqrt6}{360}& \frac{296-169\sqrt6}{1800}& \frac{-2+3\sqrt6}{225}
\\
\frac{4+\sqrt{6}}{10}& \frac{296+169\sqrt6}{1800}&\frac{88+7\sqrt6}{360}& \frac{-2-3\sqrt6}{225}
\\
1&\frac{16-\sqrt6}{36}&\frac{16+\sqrt6}{36} &\frac19
\\\hline
&\frac{16-\sqrt6}{36}&\frac{16+\sqrt6}{36} &\frac19
\end{array}
So it is a fully implicit method, and the point of the last stage is also the next point of the solution approximation.

Comment: I can't use the Butcher tableau, as I am trying to code it in Python.

Comment: I do not follow, what has the representation form of the coefficients to do with the implementation language?

Comment: I wouldn't know where to use Newton's method to solve the equations

Comment: You get a system of implicit equations $k_i=hf(t+c_ih,y+a_{i1}k_1+a_{i2}k_2+a_{i3}k_3)$ which can be solved with a Newton or Newton-like method.

Comment: So the unknowns here are the k1,k2 and k3 and not the y?

Comment: Yes, the step is to compute $y_{+1}=y+\Delta y$ at time $t+\Delta t$ from $y$ at time $t$. So there are two time-consuming parts that have to be addressed carefully for an efficient implementation, computation of an approximation of the Jacobian and the factorization of the system matrix for the Newton step. Doing both only once makes this a simplified Newton method, with carefully extrapolated initial values this should not matter for the required 1-3 Newton loops. For more details and tricks read the cited book.

Comment: Are the equations as edited in the main question body correct?

Comment: Yes. To try out this method you could simply use scipy.optimize.fsolve with suitable initial values and error tolerances, more effort is only required when coding for efficiency.

Comment: I am having trouble implementing it to solve for the Robertson ODE equations. Here we have 3 coupled ODEs and 3 variables.

Comment: @joni Can you help me implement the Radau for the Robertson system of ODEs please?

Comment: Have you considered using `solve_ivp` with the option `method="Radau"`? Is your task really to implement the method yourself? Are there sufficient reasons for this like experiments with the step size control?

Comment: I need to implement myself. I've already done one implementation using Implicit Euler method. In this case, since we have to apply Newton 3 times for each step, and since there are 3 ODEs and 3 variables, that would mean an application of 81. So I already made Jacobian 9x9. The error is calling on the 4th iteration a 'Singular Matrix'! Can I post my Python script for you to have a look?

Comment: In my opinion, this would deserve the opening of  a new question, however with a toss-up between here and scicomp.SE. Also, the code should be well commented, in-code or in surrounding text, explaining the main design decisions (non-linear solver method selected, step size strategy etc.) A complete test case is also always useful.

Comment: I am opening a new post with inclusion of my Python code. How do I refer it to you?

Comment: You can put a link here in a comment or add it to the question as a "follow-up".

Comment: btw I cannot import solve_ivp and/or Raday!

Comment: `from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp`, the scipy version should be recent enough, >1.1 better 1.4. While there is a `Radau` stepper class, you do not need to import that, the option string is sufficient.

Comment: my new post with code: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3677767/radau-iia-5th-order-implementation-in-python